# How to disconnect circles if noise is present and detect circle if edges are broken?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to detect all the optical circles but i am facing difficulties where edges of circle are quite broken. Somewhere, circles are touching each other after binarization due to noise. Is there any approach to solve it?

```
pattern = [{0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9},
        {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9}
    ]   
stringLen = len(pattern)
blobCnts = sum([len(d) for d in pattern])

raw_image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(raw_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

bloblist = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
blobcnts = contours.sort_contours(bloblist)[0]
contour_list = []
sorted_contour = []
for blob in blobcnts:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(blob,0.01*cv2.arcLength(blob,True),True)
        area = cv2.contourArea(blob)
        (x,y),r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(blob)
        center = (int(x),int(y))
        r = int(r)
        if ((len(approx) >= 8) & (len(approx) <= 23) & (area > 30) & (8 < r < 20)):
            contour_list.append(blob)

numlist = []
if blobCnts == len(contour_list):
        for (l, i) in enumerate(np.arange(0, blobCnts, stringLen)):
            cnts = contours.sort_contours(contour_list[i:i + 10],method="top-to-bottom")[0]
            numlist.append(cnt)

print cnt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If circles are filled, get edges using Canny. Then apply a Hough transform. That is robust for circles with missing pixels, occlusion, and so forth.

Hough transforms work on a "voting" system. Each possible circle is voted for by each pixel (if it is on it). It follows you have to use it a bit differently depending on prior information. If you know you have exactly one pixel, choose the highest. If you know you have exactly two, choose the highest, then exclude any circles very close to it (which are probably votes for the same circle) and take the next highest independent circle. If you don't know the number, you have to establish both your threshold and your minimum distance between circles (generally you'll want to disallow overlap by less than about a quarter radius).

Comment: I applied it but i am not able to fine tune it as per my requirement

Comment: I implemented but how can i fix some parameters for all images? It's changing based on illumination

Comment: function contains param1 which defines threshold for canny. I set it to initially 30, at that time from 100 circles i got 99 circles for few samples. later on, when i reduced it, rate to detect 100 circles was reduced. Later on, i detected edge by canny first and then i passed edge image as input to this function. Onwards, only 2 was rejected from 58 samples. So, i just want to ask is what is the conclusion of this scenario?

Comment: Is there any algorithm/ method should be followed before houghcircle?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) example from opencv sounds like your problem (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)
[image]